# Cassandra read process example

Tags: cassandra

I was reading https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/dml/dmlAboutReads.html and got confused when I reach Partition Key Cache.

I understand that in the Partition Key Cache you can read partition key's index，then use index to find the disk location in compression offset map, so you don't need to do the Partition Summary step.

After a sstable pass Bloom Filter, it may have the partition key. For example: sstable1 has pk1, pk2; keycache.pk1 = index0, keycache.pk2 = index0; compresset_offset_map.index0 = location0

Here are the questions:

1. Why not keycache just directly save the location? so you don't need to look up hashtable twice.
2. Since every partition key in the same sstable has the same index, so why not use set data structure to look up instead of a hashtable?

It could be I understand it wrong and gave the the example wrong

I don't understand how Partition Summary works either.

Can someone please give me a specific example of how it actually works?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
1. The concept of Partition key cache, is based on the fact that partition keys     are always stored in sorted order.
2. Partition summary is off-heap memory structure. and is based on sampling of partition keys which are present in partition index.    
3. Partition index file is stored on disk. and this file stores index of all partition keys along with their mapped offset.
```

Assume the partition index file has 50 partition keys : From Key01 - Key50.

As mentioned earlier, partition summary is based on sampling,
if we have set the partition summary to sample every 10 partition keys, then memory    of partition summary would contain the information of FIVE partition keys and their location on disk within the partition index.

```
For example, (This should be likely structure of Partition key cache)

Partition Key 01 -> location of PK01 from Partition index File
Partition Key 11 -> location of PK11 from Partition index File
Partition Key 21 -> location of PK21 from Partition index File
Partition Key 31 -> location of PK31 from Partition index File
Partition Key 41 -> location of PK41 from Partition index File
```

Now, if query contains the request for Partition Key 33, it would start scanning the partition key cache, which is in memory and helps in faster scanning, it would come to know range where Parition key 33 is present, i.e in between Partition Key 31 and Partition Key 41

So, it directly goes to the location of PK31 in the index file based on the information provided by the summary. It then performs a very quick scan from Partition Key 31 and Partition Key 41.

In short, partition summary helps us to quickly pin point the location of partition key within the part index, instead of searching each and every partition key from partition index file.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks it helps. The value stored in the partition key is scattered at different sstables. I assume that partition key cache, use partition key and sstable to look up the location. Since sstable are all listed in the key cache (if it is cached), why do we even bother to use the bloom filter to filter all the sstable first? How does compresset_offset_map come in to play?